# Can't add heading number in the table caption

Tags: microsoft-word, caption

I need to add heading number in the caption of the picture. Everything is fine upto a certain section:
[image]

But then, the heading number is not showing up:
[image]

The heading only starts with zero. I don't know what is wrong. I have checked heading and breaks and everything is correct. I even transferred file in other versions of world. But, it is showing me the same error. Small file link is [given below](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lTJIo_92nvcEk4eGtGaYe0QhlBGSvbY3iDeJ4uBYouU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please post a small file example.

Comment: @harrymc I have given a small file link

Comment: Was this file before or after adding the heading? Because I can't see any problem. But you do have a mess as regarding heading levels: Having a heading 1 and below it a heading 4 is simply not done: There should be heading 2 and heading 3 in the middle. Headings should be sequentially in order or what you get is a mess.

Comment: @harrymc  Then why am I not able to add  Chapter number in the caption?. I added only a section of original file and deliberately added a heading number so that it will be shown. That's why its a mess.

Comment: In my experience, you often can't trust how Word displays updated headings when there are tracked changes and those modifications are not yet accepted. My advice is to copy the entire contents of the file into a new, empty document, then accept all changes in that new document and see how the table and section numbering looks without pending changes

Comment: @Ring I have copied the tracked changes. But still, it is giving me same error.

Comment: Okay, you did accept all, right? Do you set up your sections and list numbering using named multi-level lists or do you let Word handle things? Word can forget what it's doing on occasion and disassociate a list of headings. It happens more often when Word handles the lists on its own. It can happen with a multi-level list, too, but much less often. Step back two section headings, select each heading in turn, apply Normal, then re-apply their original section heading. Does the first caption even have the right chap. number? My Co. blocks google docs so I can't check your file.